# Parallel one Optional AND one ParamArray in a sub

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not so professional in [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [vs2012](/questions/tagged/vs2012) [vb](/questions/tagged/vb), and now I've a problem:

This is the declaration of the sub:

```
Public Sub DocFill(ByVal DocName As String, ByVal Optional OK As Boolean=False, ByVal ParamArray BmValues() As String)
```

And the error message is:

> Error 7   'BmValues' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I tried change the order, but the last value always drop this error

Is possible to declare soehow parallely this two params or not?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to show some more code. On which line you are getting the error and how are you calling your sub

Comment: [Parameter Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx): "All parameters preceding the parameter array must be required. The parameter array must be the only optional parameter."

Comment: Try: `ByVal ParamArray BmValues() As Variant`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to cook up something like this:

```
Public Sub DocFill(ByVal DocName As String, ByVal ParamArray BmValues() As Object) ' Declare BmValues as an array of Object.
    Dim OK As Boolean = False ' Declare the OK Boolean within the method.

    If BmValues.Length > 0 Then ' Check whether BmValues contains anything.
        If BmValues(0).GetType() is GetType(Boolean) Then ' Check whether BmValues' first value is a Boolean.
            OK = CBool(BmValues(0)) ' If so, set OK to the first value in BmValues.
        End If

        ...

    End If

    ...

End Sub
```